# How to call a subclass method from superclass?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

Java newbie here.

`Banana and Apple extend Fruit` (`Fruit` might as well be an abstract class since no Fruit will ever be instanciated).

`Banana` and `Apple` both have a (wildly different) `toString()` method.

A method somewhere -- let's call it `processFruit(Fruit fruit)` -- accepts `Fruit` as a parameter, and then calls the `toString()` method of the actual `Fruit` received (meaning, either a banana or an apple), for logging purposes. How do I do this?

I would like to do fruit.toString() and have it run the Apple.toString() or Banana.toString() method based on what the fruit actually is.

Things I'd rather not do (because there are many fruits, not just apples and bananas):

1. Have two distinct `processFruit` methods, `processFruit(Banana banana)` and `processFruit(Apple apple)`, because the code is identical
2. Downcast the received fruit to either Apple or Banana, and then call its `toString()` method

There must be another way but I can't see it.

Comment: Check out this Java tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to do fruit.toString() and have it run the Apple.toString() or Banana.toString() method based on what the fruit actually is.

That's *exactly* what will happen automatically, so long as you're really overriding the existing parameterless `toString()` method. That's how method overriding works.

If you want to do this for a method other than `toString()` (which is declared in `Object`) you'd want to create an abstract method in `Fruit`, and then implement it in each subclass. You can then call it on any `Fruit` instance, and the right implementation will be called.

Full example:

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class Fruit {
    public abstract String getColor();
}

class Banana extends Fruit {
    @Override public String getColor() {
        return "yellow";
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    @Override public String getColor() {
        return "green";
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
        list.add(new Banana());
        list.add(new Apple());

        for (Fruit fruit : list) {
            System.out.println(fruit.getColor());
        }
    }
}
```

See the [inheritance part of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more details.

Comment: You could also make an `abstract` toString method in `Fruit` which would force an extending class to implement their own version.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Yup, that's true.

Comment: Thanks... I missed the whole @Override concept!

Answer (score 0):

Just call `fruit.toString()`.  If the fruit is a Banana, then Banana's `toString()` method will be called. If it's an Apple, then Apple's `toString()` method will be called. That's what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the first thing I tried, and I got an error; can't test it right now but I'll try to get back and explain what the error was.